# Android: BoundService and leaked ServiceConnection

Tags: android, service

I am confused.

I have an application which I believe needs to implement a service.  This service is specific to the application; when the application actually dies or is manually terminated, the service can go away.  The application will be in constant communication with the service, ideally by the activity calling methods of the service itself.

This implies to me that the service should be a Bound Service.

However, when I rotate the phone after having bound the service, the main activity calls onStop(), and I get a leaked serviceConnection squawk.  I thought the whole point of services was *not* to nuke themselves when application rotated, or lost focus, etc.

I suppose I could simply disable the rotation feature in the application, but that's sub-optimal because  having a different layout for different orientations is highly desired.  It also seems to be just bad form to do this, because if some other application takes the focus I'll still run into the same problem.

I think (but am not sure) that if this were a started service, the call to onStop() would be circumvented, but then I could not call methods on it.

How is this done in practice:  How do I get a service implemented so that I can call methods on it directly, but not have the OS complain when I rotate the phone?  Is there way to start the method in the activity and then bind to it?  Would that even work?

Comment: You need to bind to the `Service` in `onStart()` of the `Activity` and make sure you 'unbind' in the `onStop()` method.

Comment: But if I unbind the service, doesn't that stop the service?

Comment: Not if you've also called `startService(...)` in which case it will run indefinitely until an explicit call to `stopService(...)` or the `Service` calls its own `stopSelf()` method.

Comment: Aha.  Okay, so my hunch was correct.  Write it up as an answer and I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: Sure - give me a few minutes and I'll post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought the whole point of services was not to nuke themselves when application rotated, or lost focus, etc.

That is correct. The problem you have is subtly different however. Assuming you have a `ServiceConnection` in your `Activity` similar to the following...

```
MyService mService = null;
boolean mBound = false;

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        mService = null;
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

...you can see that mService holds a reference to your `Service` object. When you rotate your phone the system is attempting to destroy and re-create your `Activity` but unless you 'nullify' the `mService` reference (by unbinding), then it causes a leaked `ServiceConnection`. Consequently you need to bind/unbind accordingly, e.g., in `onStart` and `onStop` respectively.

To prevent the `Service` from being killed when it's unbound, just make sure you always call `startService(...)` at some point in your `Activity`. This ensures the `Service` will continue to run until it is explicitly stopped using `stopService(...)` or if the `Service` calls its own `stopSelf()` method.

Comment: You are a scholar and a gentlesophant.